# Vue - scroll event listener not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header in my Vue component, that I am trying to make "sticky":

```
<app-header id="header"></app-header>

#header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0px;
}
```

So, then I have tried to set the position fixed on scrolling to the header like this:

```
methods: {
  handleScroll () {
    const header = document.querySelector('#header');
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const rect = header.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const headerTop = rect.top + scrollTop;

    if (window.scrollY > headerTop) {
      header.classList.add('fixed');
      content.classList.add('content-margin');
    } else {
      header.classList.remove('fixed');
      content.classList.remove('content-margin');
    }
  }
},
beforeMount () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
beforeDestroy () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

I am adding to the `header` the class `fixed`:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed!important;
}
```

But, when I scroll, the classes keep being removed and added to `header` and `content`, only when I stop scrolling the right classes are in place. How can I stop this behaviour?

Here is the stripped down, basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q6rbzj7/36/) that is not made in Vue, of how it should like.

Comment: Please post a working snippet

Comment: @SauravRastogi https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: You're not going to find the best browser support for `position: sticky`.  You'd be better with  a pure javascript approach and a combination of fixed/relative positioning. https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: As others have commented, without the code its hard to know for sure, but as [support (caniuse.com)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) for `position:sticky` is still very new (edge, safari) or incomplete (ff, chrome), this may not be practical yet.

Comment: well, but even when I change to only position relative and then change that with JS to position fixed, the screen is still flickering

Comment: @RobertWade I am using only js approach, and that is where I am having flickering issues

Comment: My point was to get rid of the use of sticky as positioning.  can you post a complete working example that replicates the error?

Comment: I did get rid of the sticky as positioning for the header, I have replaced it with the position relative, I will try to post fiddle about it

Comment: I have made a fiddle for it